# Fiddler not picking up Content-Type

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to test some calls but the content-type is text no matter what I do.  I try to specify as json or xml but it doesn't matter and not sure why:

[image]

Comment: right-click and choose to open the image in a new tab to see it in higher resolution so it's clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting confused about the **Content-Type** column, which shows the Content-Type of the **response**, not the **request**.

Double-click the Web Session to inspect the request and response using the Inspectors. The Request is shown in the top set of tabs while the Response is shown in the bottom set.